# Mongo query, grouping array entries

Tags: mongodb

- I have a mongo collection names ***books***. Structure as follows.
- I want to know if I have duplicated any characters in each book in my collection.
- For example In first book character **'anne'** repeated. So, I need to filter those such records. 
  **Example :**

  `{
       title : 'abc',
       characters : 
        [
          { name : 'Anne',id :2},
          { name : 'Suzan', id :1},
          { name : 'Anne', id:2}
        ]
    }
   {
           title : 'xyz',
           characters : 
           [
            { name : 'Anne', id :2},
            { name : 'Suzan', id : 1}
           ]
     }`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there is _id property for each document, You can try like below query:

```
db.books.aggregate([
  {$project: { _id: 1, characters: 1 } },
  {$unwind: "$characters" },
  {$group: {_id: { _id: "$_id", name: "$characters.name" }, count: { $sum: 1 }}},
  {$match: {"count" : { $gt: 1 }}}
])
```

Result should come like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "_id" : ObjectId("someid"), "name" : "Anne" }, "count" : 2 }
```

let me know if its work.